# web service REST with GX17/ .NET

Tags: .net, rest, web-services, genexus

I've tried to generate a web service REST with Genexus and when I tried to consume it the result is Error 404 from SoapUI or Postman. When I tried to consume it from a webpanel in GX the error on the server is IHttpHandler Exception.

The procedure has the following properties:

```
Expose as web server: TRUE
REST Protocol: TRUE
Generate OpenAPI interface: TRUE
```

I try to consume it like this: http://myHostNameOrIPAddress/MyVirtualDir/ws_procName?parm=value
or
http://myHostNameOrIPAddress/MyVirtualDir/ws_procName.aspx?parm=value

I don't know if I have to put the ".aspx" or not because the procedure, as the GXWiki said, isn't main. I also tried to know if the ws is active using this URL:

http://myHostNameOrIPAddress/MyVirtualDir/ws_procName.aspx?wadl

And after no having any success, I tried to consume it with a gx web panel with httpclient like this:

```
&HttpClient.Host = "http://myHostNameOrIPAddress" 
&HttpClient.BaseUrl= "/MyVirtualDir/"
&HttpClient.Port   = 80 
&HttpClient.Secure = 0 
&HttpClient.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8") 
&JsonSend = &ws_sdtInput.ToJson() //&ws_sdtInput is the sdt of the input parameter after import the OpenAPI 

&HttpClient.AddString(&JsonSend.Trim()) 
&HttpClient.Execute("POST", "/messages/ws_procName.json") 
&JsonResponse = &ws_sdtOutput.ToJson()  //&ws_sdtOutput is the sdt of the output parameter after import the OpenAPI

&JsonResponse = &HttpClient.ToString()
```

Anyone can help me? thanks in advance :)

Comment: You haven't posted any code...

Comment: It would be good if you could specify whether you are using the Java or .NET generator, as well as the version of Genexus you are using.

The 404 error means that it cannot be found, and the reasons could be:


* You forgot to include \rest\ in the URL when consuming it.

* You don't have URLRewrite installed.

* You are using Tomcat 10.1 and generating with a version prior to GX18.

It would be helpful if you could add some additional information to the execution context, so we can assist you better.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you @ealmeida for answering my post!! I'm using Gx 17 generating .Net with IIS7.  Where do I have to put \rest\ in the URL when consuming? The URLRewrite is installed in the server but I really don't know how the configuration properties has to be set.

Comment: I edit my question in order to add some additional information about the situation hoping to make it easier for yo to understand it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you've never used that service and you're already generating OpenAPI, what you can do is import the **default.yaml** file into a tool like Postman to consume the REST service.
There it will show you how to write the URL and how to pass the parameters.
It takes a bit of work at the beginning, but by looking at the documentation, you shouldn't have any problems.

You can read https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?15314,HowTo%3A+Consume+a+Procedure+exposed+as+a+Rest+service

Comment: Thank you so much!! I'll take a look at the documentation and try again with your bits of advice. Regards!